# How to include a JS file in this theme?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

This makes the Jquery script work in a plugin:

`wp_enqueue_script('metabox_js', plugins_url('add_meta_box/js/metabox.js',dirname(__FILE__) ), array('jquery'));`

I have been trying for ages, & this doesn't make the script work in a theme (have put this in functions.php):

```
function prefix_enqueue_scripts3() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'metabox_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/metabox.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
                  }  

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','prefix_enqueue_scripts3');
```

Please can someone advise. I have another Jquery file further up functions.php, which uses Jquery successfully, I have only changed the file location and file name with this one. Please can someone advise? Thank-you!

Comment: This looks correct. Does the metabox not load? One thing to note is that in prefix_enqueue_scripts3 you are setting the script to load in the footer, not sure if that might be causing your issue.

Comment: The metabox is shown in the `add new post` area. This Jquery file is suppose to hide the metabox and only show when a category is selected. I'm trying to make this work for the `add new post` editor area. Could loading in the footer cause this issue? How should I do it please? Thank-you!

Comment: I changed `true` to `false` and it didn't make any difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) action:

> `wp_enqueue_scripts` is the proper hook to use when enqueuing items that are meant to appear **on the front end**.

For admin-facing scripts, the correct action hook is [`admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts)

```
function prefix_enqueue_scripts3() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'metabox_js',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/metabox.js',
        array( 'jquery' ),
        '1.0.0',
        true
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_enqueue_scripts3' );
```

Comment: Thank-you, that doesn't seem to have solved my problem either though.

Comment: I looked at the Jquery file, if I list more than one category to show the metabox for it works, if I add one it does not. I'll have to work that out. Thank-you for the help Milo!